# How to submit forms using PHP and Goutte on a JavaScript-driven website with JSF?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, jsf

how are you?
I'm trying to access the tables on the website https://registrocivilminas.org.br using PHP. To do this, I'm using the Goutte library. First, I log in using the credentials:

```
$login = '83698487373';
$senha = 'teste123456';
```

This is how I enter the site:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Goutte\Client;

// URL do formulário de login
$urlLogin = 'https://registrocivilminas.org.br/e-civil/pages/usuario/login.jsf';

// Seus dados de login
$login = '83698487373';
$senha = 'teste123456';

// Inicializa o cliente Goutte
$client = new Client();

// Faz o login
$crawler = $client->request('GET', $urlLogin);
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Entrar')->form();
$form['j_idt15'] = $login;
$form['senha'] = $senha;
$client->submit($form);
```

It worked very well, but when I try to access the 'Certidão via Correios' menu via code and get the link, I simply can't because the site uses JavaScript codes with JSF. So, I decided to place the form inside the HTML and try to submit it to see if I can retrieve the table, like this:

```
$html = $client->getResponse()->getContent();

$onclick1 = "jsf.util.chain(this,event,'PF(\'statusDialog\').show();','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'formBuscarCertidao\'),{\'voltar\':\'voltar\'},\'\')');return false";
$onclick2 = "jsf.util.chain(this,event,'PF(\'statusDialogConsulta\').show();','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'formBuscarCertidao\'),{\'salvar\':\'salvar\'},\'\')');return false";

$html = '<form id="formBuscarCertidao" name="formBuscarCertidao" method="post"
action="/e-civil/pages/certidao/buscarCertidao.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
class="form-horizontal">
<input type="hidden" name="formBuscarCertidao" value="formBuscarCertidao">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-wrapper" aria-expanded="true">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="form-body">
                        <h3 class="box-title">Buscar certidão - Correio
                        </h3>
                        <hr>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <strong>Nome da pessoa:</strong><br><input name="j_idt93" maxlength="100"
                                    type="text" class="form-control" value="a">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12"><input id="idCheckConfirmaDados" type="checkbox"
                                    name="idCheckConfirmaDados"><label for="idCheckConfirmaDados"
                                    style="margin-left:5px;">Pesquisar pelo nome idêntico</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <strong>Pessoa associada (Mãe ou Cônjuge):</strong><br><input name="j_idt97"
                                    maxlength="100" type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <strong>Municipio:</strong><select id="comboMunicipio" name="comboMunicipio"
                                    class="form-control" size="1">
                                    <option value="">Selecione...</option>
                                    <option value="7068" selected>Abadia dos Dourados</option>
                                    <option value="7069">Abaeté</option>
                                    <option value="7070">Abre-Campo</option>
                                    <option value="7071">Acaiaca</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>

                    <hr><a id="voltar" href="#"
                        onclick="'. $onclick1 .'"
                        class="btn btn-default">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-left"></i>Voltar
                    </a><a id="salvar" href="#"
                        onclick="'. $onclick2 .'"
                        class="btn btn-fill btn-primary pull-right">
                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-right"></i>Pesquisar
                    </a>

                    <br>
                    <hr>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                                <strong><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Sobre os prazos:</strong>

                                <br>
                                <br>

                                <p>Desde 2013, todos os registradores civis de Minas Gerais alimentam diariamente o
                                    sistema e, atualmente, o banco de dados contém todos os
                                    registros realizados no Estado. São mais de 10 milhões de registros disponíveis
                                    até o momento. Estarão disponíveis os registros realizados desde 1º de janeiro
                                    de 1950.</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:3"
    value="7568896828986541216:715917054598450290" autocomplete="off">
</form>';

$form = $crawler->selectButton('Pesquisar')->form();
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
```

But it didn't work. Can someone help me?